# Validating tokens in an Android app is unusual?

Tags: android, jwt, token

I was trying to find a way to validate tokens in my Android app, however I read somewhere [here](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt/issues/131) that "*It's unusual for an Android app to verify or even sign a token.*" Why is it unusual? Does this mean that there is no way of verifying tokens in native apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly lets understand what makes a token usable as a stateless auth agent. basically JWT is just a json object which has 3 parts

- header
- payload
- signature

Signature method is sha256(base64(header)+base64(payload)+"secret message").

"secret message" defines how strong the token is. server verifies the validity of the token which this secret key.

Now if you would like to verify the token on your client side, you definitely need this secret key. DOING THIS WILL COMPROMISE THE SECURITY :)

Hope I was able to shed some light on why we should not verify the token on client side. Let's leave the verification to server.